# Running Node.js Commands in the Windows Command Prompt

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

In Linux, if I run the following command in the CLI:

```
node -e 'console.log( "Hello, world!" );'
```

I get the expected output:

```
Hello, world!
```

However, in Windows, if I run

```
node -e 'console.log( "Hello, world!" );'
```

Even though I have Node.js v12.8.0 installed, I get:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

How can I run Node.js commands like console.log() from the Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but seems like a it's just Quotation mark error because this worked for me

```
node -e  "console.log('Hello World')"
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's crazy! So in Windows, I have to use double quotes to signify the Node.js command while in Linux the opposite is true. Thanks very much for your help. Does anyone know why? It must be something to do with Windows CLI syntax.

Comment: I believe its just a windows CMD thing because I tried the above command that you used in Linux in my GIT BASH (its linux based) and i got the desired result as you mentioned